# Prevent unnecessary apps from running in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I have 4 runnable projects(specifically web apps) in a single solution. The problem  is when i try to run visual studio all the above mentioned apps getting run in background, but not in browser. However the setup is such that only one app is meant to run. `Startup Project` is set as `Single startup project` only

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the below steps in Visual Studio

1. Select the project you want to stop running in background
2. press `F4` (this will open properties of the project, but not the property page opens by `right click > property`)
3. Set Always Start When Debugging to false

But remember this is a user to user configuration. You cannot set it for all your team members

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on Solution.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select a single Startup Project
   [image]

Comment: Sorry i have already mentioned the solution is on `Single startup project`. Doesn't work